# Como empilhar modals do Bootstrap com o backdrop acima do modal anterior?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

como seria possível modificar o modal do Bootstrap para que quando houver uma pilha de modals abertos, o backdrop de cada um aberto fique acima dos demais? o que eu observei até agora?

quando abre um Modal, o `z-index` do modal é de 1050, e o backdrop é de 1040, e sempre será 1040 indenpendente de quantos modals estão abertos... então pensei que para contornar isso, teria que ser possível usar o evento "show.bs.modal" e ao abrir os modals, ele incrementar o z-index do backdrop para que fique acima dos modals anteriores, e é nesta parte que estou preso.

um exemplo seria esse fiddle que embora já carregue os modals ele só empilha o backdrop se você fechar todos e ir clicando em abrir modal no botão dentro dele
http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/314/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme a resposta aceita [Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay) você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
    $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, ajudou duas pessoas, tinha um outro cara querendo saber a mesma coisa haha!

Comment: isso funciona também se o modal abrir sem o evento click, se for onload por exemplo?

Comment: Sim... esse método irá funcionar em qualquer tipo de acionamento da função modal do bootstrap. =)